# Redirect PuTTY Streams

Tags: logging, redirect, putty

Is it possible to redirect the PuTTY streams so I can send the 2 streams ( input and output ) to my own program for processing ? The logging option logs all input and output. I would like it separated and sent on the fly to my program. If this is not possible I will have to delve into the source and grab the IO just after it is entered into the program and just before it is received.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to differentiate between "Putty streams" and "shell streams".

To get both error and stdout into one file :-
`ls >> file 2>&1`

to separate :-
`ls 2>>stderr_file 1>>stdout_file`

`stdin, stdout, and stderr are 0, 1, and 2, respectively`

Comment: I want to be able to get those streams from the side which is connecting via PuTTY. eg. If I'm going from Windows to Linux I want to be able to access those streams in Windows on-the-fly. I looked into hooking into PuTTY's sending/receiving but I realised it sends a character one at a time as you type it in real time which complicates things. I could potentially redirect to a buffer which gets flushed when the user hits Enter or something but it seems a messy method.

Comment: run the script in the background (or another shell) and then `tail -f logfile`, then the log file will be visible on the Putty terminal. You can save putty logs of everything that is incomming, or scp the file at points in time.

Comment: Hi Ian. Thanks for your help on this issue. Ideally I want to be able to grab each command as it's sent then be able to grab back out the corresponding output. This should happen transparently in the background whilst PuTTY is being used.